# Customising a marker after performing a spatial search query

Tags: leaflet, query, markers, geodjango, search

I'm have a geodjango app that uses leaflet for a front-end. I have integrated the search function on the front-end to be able to search a customer location in real-time, of which the code below does that perfectly and I'm happy. But the challenge now is after it displays the marker on the map, I'm unable to use the following code(see below) to customise the marker to show a pop up message ontop of the marker saying "I'm here" for example. i'm not sure what am I missing ?

```js
<!-- search function for customer location -->
var searchControl = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch().addTo(map);

var results = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

searchControl.on('results', function (data) {
    results.clearLayers();
    for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
    }

<!-- Trying to customise the marker after the marker is placed on the map after performing a spatial search query above-->
L.marker(result).addTo(map)
      .bindPopup('Hi, I am here.<br> Which services are nearby?')
      .openPopup();
```

Comment: When do you wan to customize marker? At the time of creation of marker or much later, when marker is already on the map?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know aht `result` is but you can use this code:

```
searchControl.on('results', function (data) {
    results.clearLayers();
    for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        L.marker(data.results[i].latlng).addTo(results)
           .bindPopup('Hi, I am here.<br> Which services are nearby?')
           .openPopup();
    }
}
```